# How to set client tags on trino using SQLAlchemy

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, presto, trino

I want to set the client tags submitted with each query using SQLAlchemy API. I have created engine like below

```
engine = create_engine(url,
                           connect_args={'protocol': 'https',
                                         'requests_kwargs': {
                                             'cert': (cert file path, key file Path),
                                             'verify': False
                                         },
                                         'session_props': {
                                             'query_max_execution_time': '6h',
                                             'query_max_run_time': '8h'
                                         }
                                         })
```

Answer (score 0):

So I figured out the way, I needed to install trio &
SQLAlchemy's specific versions

```
SQLAlchemy==1.4.46
trino==0.320.0
```

& then modified my code as below

```
url = URL(user=user, password=pass, host=host, port=8080, catalog=catalog, schema=schema)

engine = create_engine(url,
                           connect_args={
                               "session_properties": {'join_distribution_type': 'BROADCAST',
                                                      'query_max_execution_time': '6h',
                                                      'query_max_run_time': '8h'
                                                      },
                               "client_tags": ["test","test2"],
                               "http_scheme": "https",
                               "verify": False,
                               "source": "Demo"
                           }
                     )
```